# pretty simple ... considering set in for loop

Tags: batch-file

i dont know.. but i think this seems to be a pretty dumb question, so please forgive me if i just cant find my own solution, kinda tried it the whole day. :(

so thats my code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set pfad="C:\Temp\*"

for /d %%i in (%pfad%) do (
   set _sum=dir /b /s /a:d %%i\* | find /v "" /c
)
ENDLOCAL
```

the output should be 1 then 0 then 2, because i have 3 folders in Temp, the first one containing 1 subfolder, the 2nd 0 subfolder and the last one 2, but i just get 0 0 0!!
the moment i let the set _sum= away, everything is fine, correct output.
so how do i get the _sum to behave the way i want it to? ^-^'

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a variable directly to the output of a command in batch. You need to run the command through a for loop and set the variable to the variable of the for loop.

```
for /d %%i in (%pfad%) do (
    for /f %%A in ('dir /b /s /a:d %%i\* ^| find /v "" /c') do (
        set _sum=%%A
        echo !_sum!
    )
)
```